# Script to duplicate categories as tags

Tags: categories, tags

I have a site with 900+ posts, each with about 3-5 categories. I would like to copy each of the categories to be a tag and am looking for the SQL code to do just that. I do not want to delete or overwrite the categories. (I assume that's the best thing to do for SEO purposes?)

I am having a hard time figuring out exactly what needs to be INSERTed.

What I have so far... It's the comments at the end I need help with.

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id, $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id, $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id, $wpdb->terms.term_id, $wpdb->terms.name, $wpdb->terms.slug
FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
($wpdb_posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON
($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->terms.name NOT LIKE '*%'
ORDER BY post_date DESC
";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

$insert = "";

$wpdb->query($insert);

-- Next steps:
-- LOOP? {
--  INSERT INTO $wpdb->terms (name, slug)
--  VALUES (terms.name, terms.slug)
-- }
-- SELECT new term_id's for the above inserted names and slugs
-- LOOP? {
--  INSERT INTO $wpdb->term_taxonomy (term_id, taxonomy)
--  VALUES (terms.term_id, post_tag)
-- }
-- SELECT new term_taxonomy_id's for the above inserted term_id's
-- LOOP? {
--  INSERT INTO $wpdb->term_relationships (term_taxonomy_id, object_id)
--  VALUES (term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id, post_id)
-- }
```

Comment: I really do think it is a bad idea to use a custom SQL query to change terms from hierarchical to non hierarchical. There are a few issues which can cause you a couple of really bad headaches

Comment: OK - what exactly is hierarchical vs. non-hierarchical, in this situation?  Also, do you have a better solution?

Comment: I think I misunderstood something here, do you want to change categories to tags, or simply take each category, duplicate it but instead of making the duplicate a category, you make it a tag

Comment: BTW, hierarchical taxonomies like `category` have terms which can have parents and children, non hierarchical taxonomies like `post_tag` have terms that does not have parents or children

Comment: I want to duplicated the categories, and make them tags.  I want to keep the categories, as is, for SEO purposes.  But I also want to have them as tags.

Comment: All of the categories appear to be top-level categories (no children).

Answer (score 5):

As I said, we would rather use native functions here, which is safer and already does all the hard work for you. We need to be very careful here as this is a very expensive operation to run. Not doing this correctly can crash your site due to timing out

Your worksflow is also wrong here. I would first create all the tags, and after that, insert the tags into the posts. You are trying to do all at once.

Lets us first grab all the categories and use that info to create tags. Just note:

- `post_tag` being a non hierarchical taxonomy cannot have any duplicate names, hierarchical taxonomies like `category` can have duplicate term names within different hierarchies. If you have categories with same names, you will get a `WP_Error` object back if you are going to try to insert tags with duplicate names. To avoid that, we will simply check if a tag exists before we try to insert it
- Tags cannot have parent/child relationships, categories can. So when we duplicate a category to be a term, we should set all parents explicitly to `0`

Here is the code: (***NOTE***: We would require PHP 5.4+)

```
// Lets create our tags. We will use wp_insert_term hooked to init
add_action( 'init', function ()
{
    // Get all categories
    $categories = get_categories( ['hide_empty' => 0] );

    // Probably totally unnecessary, but check for empty $categories
    if ( !$categories )
        return;

    // Loop through the categories and create our tags
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        // First make sure that there is no tag that exist with the same name
        if ( term_exists( $category->name, 'post_tag' ) )
            continue;

        // Set our arguments for our terms from $category
        $args = [
            'description' => $category->description,
            'parent'      => 0, // We can drop this, default is 0
            'slug'        => $category->slug,
        ];
        wp_insert_term( $category->name, 'post_tag', $args );
    } //endforeach
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

You should now see these tags in your *Tag* admin page. You can also remove the code as it is no more necessary.

Now that we have our tags created, we need to add them to our posts. Here we would need to be careful as you are talking about 900+ posts, so we do not want to break the bank.

What we will do is, we will query all of those posts, but only the post ID's which saves a lot on resources. Also, we will use `get_the_category` which are cached, so it does not require extra db calls, `wp_get_post_categories` are not cached, so it is really expensive

Due to [`wp_set_post_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms) being expensive, you would maybe need to split the following into a couple of queries, but I believe one query should be enough

Lets attach the tags to our posts

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function ()
{
    // Get all our posts
    $args = [
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Make the query lean
        // Add any additional query args here
    ];
    $q = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( !$q->have_posts() )
        return;

    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();

        // Get all the categories attached to the post
        $categories = get_the_category();
        if ( !$categories )
            continue;

        // Get the names from the categories into an array
        $names = wp_list_pluck( $categories, 'name' );
        // Loop through the names and make sure that the post does not already has the tag attached
        foreach ( $names as $key=>$name ) {
            if ( has_tag( $name ) )
                unset ( $names[$key] );
        }
        // Make sure we still have a valid $names array
        if ( !$names )
            continue; 

        // Finally, attach our tags to the posts
        wp_set_post_terms( 
            get_the_ID(), // Post ID 
            $names, // Array of tag names to attach
            'post_tag',
            true // Only add the tags, do not override
        );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
});
```

Your posts should now have tags attached to them matching the categories. You can also now remove the function as we are done

Comment: Just for interest sake, do you have any feedback on this issue. Would be interesting to know what you have used to solve this

Answer (score 1):

You requested SQL solution but SQL is not (yet) my speciality but I might still help you. SQL also seems pointless in your case because WordPress provides all nessecary tools to achieve this.

I don't recommend to run this more than once if you remove comments from the end of code. You'll understand when you'll get there.

This code "copies" all the categories of all your posts and saves them as tags. It doesn't delete categories and it also doesn't set new tags to posts. If you also want to set tags to posts, let me know.

**PS! It only works correctly if categories are not hierarchical aka without parents!**

Please let me know if there are any problems. This code should not do any harm as far as you don't remove comments from the end of the code.

---

```
<?php
global $post;

//Get ALL the posts with query
$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'post_status' => 'any'   //Change to 'publish', 'draft' or 'pending' if you don't want to get ALL post STATUSES
            );

$post_query = new WP_Query( $args );

//Declare new array of our categories which eventually become tags
$new_tags = array();

while ($post_query->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post();

     //Get all the categories names of the post and save as an array variable
     $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID, array('fields' => 'names') );

     //Loop through all categories
     foreach ( $post_categories as $category ) {

            //Check if category is already in array
            if ( ! in_array($category , $new_tags ) ) {

                 //Push category to array if it isn't in array yet
                 array_push( $new_tags, $category );
            }
     }

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();

//VERY IMPORTANT - test first without making new tags and check if everything seems to be correct 
//PS! Compare the count of items in array (starts with 0 - it's 1 less because of that) with category count in WP admin area
print_r($new_tags);


//Add new tags programmatically - don't do it if you're sure that array is correct!!
/*
foreach ( $new_tags as $tag ) {
      wp_insert_term( $tag, 'post_tag' );
} 
*/
?>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was actually just reading chapter 6 in Professional Wordpress Design and Development and it is all about using PHP and built-in WP functions to query and update the database.

Comment: This is extremely extremely expensive

Comment: expensive in time or in memory?  Also, this appears to only create a single instance of each category as a tag, whereas I want each post to have each category as a tag, even if there are multiple posts with each category to begin with.

Comment: It is but unfortunately I can't think of other automated way to "copy" all categories and make tags out of them. This should only be run once and you should choose a time when most people/visitors are asleep.

Comment: Also note to @gram - you should not have that many different categories or even tags or the purpose of them is depleted. Every post should not have it's own unique tags. These are just tools of grouping posts in order to make navigation for visitors easier, sorting for you easier and a little boost in SEO.

Comment: @gram expensive as in time, db queries and memory. This will crash your site with only a few hundred posts

Comment: Huh? Then what hardware is my server provider using? I've got multiple queries like this, some query few thousand of posts. @gram If you're not sure then don't use it, as simple as that. I was just trying to help you.

Comment: @N00b Thanks - There are only like 25 categories total.  But there are 900+ posts that each have 1-5 categories.  Now, I want each of those posts to have the same categories as tags.

Comment: @gram this code doesn't assing these new tags to posts, only programmatically make them. [Here's reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_tags) how to add tags to post but remember that this is probably going to be very expensive. If you're willing to take that risk, (Im not an expert in that) let me know and I'll update my answer with it.